# Finding function at offset loaded with ADRP/ADD

Tags: ida, disassembly, arm

I have this assembly:

```
ADRP            X8, #off_FFFFFFF006F1E960@PAGE
ADD             X8, X8, #off_FFFFFFF006F1E960@PAGEOFF
LDR             X0, [X8] ; qword_FFFFFFF0077F08A8
LDR             X8, [X0]
LDR             X8, [X8,#0x60]
BLR             X8
```

I'd like to know what is contained in X8 when BLR is called.

I tried doing `FFFFFFF006F1E960+0x60` but it points in the middle of `unk_FFFFFFF006F1E97`, specifically it points at the following bytes: `0x54,0x45,0x55,7,0xF0,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF...`. I've tried converting this into code but `command MakeCode failed`.

What exactly is this doing?

Comment: what's at `FFFFFFF0077F08A8` ?

Comment: `qword_FFFFFFF0077F08A8`, this is seemingly empty and is placed in an uninitialized segment. The only instructions I can see are `DCQ 0, DCB 0, DCB 0...`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `off_FFFFFFF006F1E960` points to `qword_FFFFFFF0077F08A8` which is probably intialized somewhere else with the actual address to be called at runtime.